# How to figure out the thread in 'View Results Tree' listener which takes maximum connect time

Tags: jmeter

I am running a thread group for 100 threads. In the
response body that we get in 'View Results Tree' listener
there is an attribute by the name 'id'.
In 'View Results in Table' there is a field by the name
'Connect Time'. I need to figure out 'id' from 'View
Results Tree' for the thread which takes the maximum
'Connect Time'. Note that 'Connect Time' is in
'View Results in Table'.
As in 'View Results in Table' we get the 'Connect Time'
for each of the threads so there a way to figure out 'id'
for that thread from 'View Results Tree'

Answer (score 0):

You can give a unique name to each request with

**prefix-threadnumber-iterationnumber**

```
R1 -${__threadNum}-${__jm__TG__idx}
```

[image]

[image]

Then you can find the associated request in the view result tree/table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I used the exact same thing but the issue is that in my case thread number is getting printed but the iteration number is getting printed as ${__jm__TG__idx}.

Comment: What is your Thread Group name? The thread group name has to be `TG`. Please ensure that there are no spaces. Also note that JMeter variables/properties are cases sensitive too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract this `id` attribute using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into `id` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Rename the current Sampler to contain this "id" attribute using [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/) and the following code:

   ```
   prev.setSampleLabel(prev.getSampleLabel() + ' ' + vars.get('id'))
   ```
3. That's it, when you run your test next time each Sampler will have the `id` attribute from the response as its postfix

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which could check the maximum connection time and provide associated id.

Define maximum connect time as a property and initialise the value to zero.
You can add the property to the user.properties or set it in a Setup Thread Group.

1. In JMETER_HOME/bin/user.properties set the initial value of the max_connect_time

```
max_connect_time=0
```

If you are using a Setup Thread group with a JSR223 Sampler add following to the script section.

```
props.put("max_connect_time", "0")
```

[image]

2. Add a Post Processor and extract the id
3. Add a JSR223 Post processor below above Post Processor and check the connect time of current sampler

```
def id=vars.get('id')

log.info("Current Connect Time " + prev.getConnectTime().toString())
if (prev.getConnectTime() > props.get("max_connect_time").toLong()) {
    def max_connect_time = prev.getConnectTime().toString()
    props.put("max_connect_time", max_connect_time)
    log.info("Current Max connect time ${prev.getConnectTime()}")
    props.put("id", "${id}")
}
```

[image]

[Sample Result](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getConnectTime--) API documentation

4. Add a TearDown Thread Group with JSR223 Sampler to log the maximum connect time and the associated id

```
log.info("Maximum Connect Time ${props.get('max_connect_time')} with id ${props.get('id')} ")
```

[image]

Note :

1. This will work for single node.